# Aligning Thumbnail horizontally

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular6

I am using Angular 7

I have used image thumbnail class of bootstrap it is aligning vertically, I want to align horizontally.

```
.thumbnail
{
text-align: center;
float: left;
}
.row
{
text-align: center;
}
```

Following is my code:

```
 <div class= "row">
 <div class = "col-xs-12">
 <button class="btn btn-success">New Recipe</button>
 </div>
 <hr>
  <div class = "col-md-12" >
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" *ngFor="let recipe of recipes">
    <img src = "{{ recipe.imagePath }}" alt="{{ recipe.name }}" class = 
     "img-responsive" class="img-thumbnail">
    <h4 class = "caption">{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
    <p class = "caption">{{ recipe.description }}</p>
</a>
<app-recepie-item></app-recepie-item>
</div>
</div>

Have created 2 objects

recipes: Recipe [] = [ new Recipe('My Sample Recipe', 'This is my first 
recipe', 'image url'),
new Recipe('Potato Recipe', 'This an actual Potato 
Recipe', 'http://coastguard.dodlive.mil/files/2014/04/unnamed-2- 
560x281.jpg')];
```

Output seems like this.

Thumbnails are displaying vertically.

I want to display horizontally.

[image]

Comment: It seems more of a CSS and Bootstrap alignment issue... These links would be useful: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: You're using `col-md-12` class of Bootstrap grid system. That means, it will use 12 of 12 columns when screen size is equal or greater than `md` size. You may want to use something like `col-md-3` to show 4 thumbnails in a row.

Comment: @Harun Yilmaz. It worked. But thumbnails are not displaying as shown in image.

Answer (score 1):

I think you no need to write more css if you using grid property of bootstrap for alignment.

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class = "col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-success">New Recipe</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" *ngFor="let recipe of recipes">
      <a href="#">
      <img src={{recipe.url}} height="100" width="100">
      <h4 class = "caption">{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
        <p class = "caption">{{ recipe.desc }}</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
recipes: any[] = [
    {name:'product_name', desc: 'Description', url: 'http://www.movingimage.us/images/homepage/features/jhe_jim_kermit.jpg'},
    {name:'product_name', desc: 'Description', url: 'http://www.movingimage.us/images/homepage/features/jhe_jim_kermit.jpg'},
    {name:'product_name', desc: 'Description', url: 'http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-8.jpg'}
    ];
```

Comment: I added this code in css   .thumbnail{
    width: 200%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 500%;

}
.thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
a .thumbnail
{
    left: 600px;
}  --- my second object from for loop is stacking up on first. What I need to add in css?

Comment: @divyadave this code is working no need to add css for horizontally or if you still have problem that please create `https://stackblitz.com/` share link with me.

Comment: @divyadave edit my answer please check. and you no need to write more and more css go through with [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_medium.asp) read this for target target device

Comment: I have shared you [link] (https://angular-fc4wdx.stackblitz.io/#) here it coming properly and in case of actual project it is not displaying properly

Comment: @divyadave its look like css conflict your base property is override from some where you can write class or css for same class name please and verify where is conflict. inspect and check which class is override your current property or you can do one thing create new class which one is not present in your project and write all css code here. this is the link which is i'm share with you.(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cgwyhc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).